# Best proportions test based on counts (accuracy, distribution, etc)

Tags: chi-squared-test, p-value, binomial-distribution, proportion

I'm trying to compare two sets of counts over totals. For example, subject 1A will have 40 out of 600, and subject 1B will have 3 out of 20. How do I compare these proportions and counts while taking the total number of reads/counts into consideration? My null would be that these proportions are the same, and my alternative would be that they are very different.

I was thinking of doing a binomial test or chi-squared, but I don't want to assume a certain distribution, and I would like it to be as nonparametric as possible. I also feel that both might pump out a lower p-value based on the number of reads, but for my data, the B (meaning subject 2B, 3B, and 4B) will most likely all have lower total reads than their counterparts (2A, 3A, and 4A). Any advice would be helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: If the process generating the events you're counting can't be reasonably described as a sequence of Bernoulli trials (by which the binomial arises directly as a consequence), you should identify which *particular* [assumptions of the Bernoulli process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_process#Definition) fail (binary outcomes on each trial, independence, or constant $p$), and that will suggest how to model it.

Comment: My goal is to count reads at multiple positions in the genome. So for Subject 1A, they'll have 50 positions, and each position will have (reads of some category / total reads). Then we sum those up (the numerators, and the denominators), and come up with a single "proportion" for the subject. So in this case, would it be safe to assume that each "position" was a trial event? In that case, I don't think it's an outcome of 0 or 1 for each position, and the positions are not independent. Although each position does end up having a constant p. Do you have any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: For each "read" (you'll have to excuse me, but I don't know precisely what a "read" is), something is either in a particular category or not in that category? Isn't that binary? (each read is either in category or not)

Comment: Sure, either there is a read or not. What i'm worried about is the depth. We're counting the reads for each position, and then summing those positions, to come up with a final read proportion, which is what we're using to do our comparisons. I'm not entirely sure how that would be binomial.

Comment: Sorry, you skipped ahead, and totally lost me. What does a position consist of? How many "reads" that are in the category of interest might be at one position?

Comment: Let's say subject 1 has position 1, 2, 3. When gathering a bunch of sequencing data, you can have sequencing information cut in different forms and spanning multiple positions. A read, is when a transcript (one of many) happens to span that position, and give you an A,C,T,G for that region. Since we have multiple transcripts, position one can have multiple reads. But position 2, could have fewer, just because there aren't that many transcripts spanning that region. So the proportions are per say, the number of As out of total reads.

Comment: so position 1 could be 3 A's out of 10, position 2, 30 As out of 90, and position 3, 4 As out of 15. We then sum up total As, and total reads coming up with a total proportion for subject A has 37/115. Ideally, we are only considering subjects where the proportions are equal for each position and total reads are also fairly equal for the most part. So the summing wouldn't be an issue in terms of skewing data. I'm more concerned about comparing this summed proportion to other proportions.

Comment: Other proportions meaning, the proportion from other subjects.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like a test that would give me accurate p-values based on a 2X2 contingency table. Like As versus Non-As on top, and then the columns being subject 1A and 1B. To see if they are different from each other. I was looking at Fischer Exact, and Barnard. Do you have any suggestions?